# Azure Machine Learning Studio pandas package update

Tags: python, pandas

I am tring on  microsoft azure ml to update pandas package.the problem is that i am trying to execute a python script and the supported python version are still at3.5 . unfortunately i did not notice that so my code is not execute cause is written on python 3.7 . so there is any way to update pandas in azure ml studio or the whole python ?? I have already try some solutions other stuckflow questions but are very old and not working

Comment: What did you try already? The more information we have about what you've tried and what hasn't worked, the more we're able to point you in the right direction for an answer. As a starting point, please [edit] your question to include any links to other Stack Overflow questions you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new "Visual Interface" in Azure ML service, which as an updated Python runtime.  It is a new architecture over the UI of Azure ML Studio:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBPCaZo9xx0